# What is the best approach on making dynamic list in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm new in Android and I want to make a dynamic list where in I'm manually adding data through a dialog fragment. The data I'm adding are saved in a `Sqlite` database. What I'm looking for is a way to re-render my list everytime the data changes. What should be the best approach in this kind of use case?

I'm considering using a `RecyclerView` so that I can have flexibility in the layout of the list. But how can I do it using `RecyclerView`?

**EDIT**:

What I mean by using `RecyclerView` is that getting the data directly from a cursor and if the database data changes the cursor will also be changed and as well as the `RecyclerView`. I know how to setup basic `recyclerview` it is just I'm stuck on dealing with dynamic list using data from a database and without using  cursor -> arraylist

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider using in this case CursorLoaders.
They are SO much faster than creating views after a manual query.

References at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html